# Sending binary files in base64 to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encoding, suitescript

I'm trying to send a binary file from NetSuite to AWS S3. I've tied to accomplish this in two ways but I always get corrupted files in S3.

- First, I've created SuiteScript that uses the amazon sdk and I'm able to send plain files. But whenever I send binary files the files are corrupted in S3.

```html
        var s3 = new AWS.S3(options);
        
        var fileObj = file.load(14676840);
        var fileContent = fileObj.getContents();

        var rawString = encode.convert({
            string: fileContent,
            inputEncoding: encode.Encoding.BASE_64,
            outputEncoding: encode.Encoding.UTF_8
        }); //Not actually using this...

        s3.putObject({
            Bucket: BUCKET,
            ACL: 'authenticated-read',
            ContentEncoding: 'base64',
            ContentType: 'application/pdf',
            Key: 'SAMPLE.pdf',
            Body: fileContent //Tried with rawString as well
        }, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                log.error(err, JSON.stringify(err));
            } else {
                log.debug(data);
            }
        });
```

- Second, I've been also trying to use Boomi for this and I have the same exact problem. Binary files are sent but corrupted. I'm more interested in making the suitescript to work but at this point any hint would be useful.[See the process here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy8Rt.png)

Does S3 putObject or the rest api work if I send a base64 string like that?

Comment: Why are you encoding the file contents before uploading? It will be stored with that encoding. Just upload the native bytes as a Buffer or stream.

Comment: AFAIK I cannot use Buffer or stream in Suitescript. Thanks!

Comment: If SuiteScript doesn't support modern JavaScript concepts such as Buffer and streams, then it seems unlikely that any up to date version of the AWS SDK for JavaScript would work in that environment either.